# Roll Printer gives extra blank space in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, airprint

I used the method,

```
- (CGFloat)printInteractionController:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController cutLengthForPaper:(UIPrintPaper *)paper
```

to determine the height of the page. And worked fine up to iOS 9 (iOS<9). But after upgrading to iOS9 it never gets called.
Is there a specific reason for that?